# Custom Cell in UITabelView can not load file

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm learning iOS and I am making exercises from UITableView. I've built my own cell for table row and I'd like to add it but I have a problem in if condition with NIB pointer. When app is reaching this point it crashes and the message is like:

`Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/myAccount/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/90329AC3-7DAB-4F74-A147-103AE240A582/BetterApplication.app> (loaded)' with name 'Cell'`

I don't understand exactly this error instead of that it can not load this file. How to solve it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SimpleTableCellTableViewCell *cell = (SimpleTableCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**USING NIB:**

The problem is that your `nib` is not named `Cell`.

**You have to insert the name of your nib file**.

Anyway encourage you to **register the nib** in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[yourTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCellNibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

I also encourage you to **use a significant name for your Nib** file instead. Use for example `MyCustomCell` or a more specific name like the name of your class  `SimpleTableCellTableViewCell`.

If you use this, the final code will be:

```
static NSString *const simpleCellTableIdentifier = @"simpleCellTableIdentifier";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //Your stuff

    [yourTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleTableCellTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:simpleCellTableIdentifier];

    //Your staff
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SimpleTableCellTableViewCell *cell = (SimpleTableCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleCellTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[SimpleTableCellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleCellTableIdentifier]
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

**USING STORYBOARD:**

You simply need to be sure to have set `Cell` as **`Identifier` of the cell** in your `storyboard`, and then write:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SimpleTableCellTableViewCell *cell = (SimpleTableCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but what do you mean writing "yourTable" ..?

Comment: i edit the post to give you a more compressible answer. For `yourTable` i mean your table view name instance. Create an `IBOutlet` for your tableView like: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SimpleTableCellTableViewCell *simpleTableView;` and use there the variable. P.S. i see that you are a newbie but i think you know that an IBOutlet is connected to the tableView in your Nib or Storyboard.

Comment: Yes I'm new in iOS. Where should I create that new variable? In which file?

Comment: What mean? in your storyboard you don't have a table? you create the table by code? ...i'm confused..maybe you are commiting some misunderstand.

Comment: I've created in Main.storyBoard new instance of TableViewController and connected it with my class: MyTableViewController. Then I've created new cell and also connected it with class. And now in file for TableViewController I'm confused with your answer with registering NIB file.

Comment: So you are not using NIB...so why in your code you use `loadNibNamed`?? So let me edit my answer

Comment: Xcode throws me this exception: reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'. I've opened my tableCell.xib file and in Assistant Editor -> Show attributes I've set Identifier to "Cell" but no progress.

Comment: Are you joking?? You say that you have a main storyboard with a tableViewController and a TableViewCell! You have not to create another storyboard for the tableViewCell! you have to set there on that TableViewController your cell prototype!!!

Comment: I do not have Cell inside TabelViewControler. It is in separate file. Please take a look at my edit with photo

Comment: Ok nothing crashes now. Thanks for it but now I have no images inside this cells and no text.

Comment: Maybe you have not clear how does tableView/customCell/OOP concept work. Have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you forget to register some reusable cell class.

Before to use cells, try to register them to your table like this:

```
[tableView registerClass:[SimpleTableCellTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

You can add this call for example, in `awakeForNib` or immediately after you create your table.

I prefer to register the cells with the same name of the class like this:

```
Class CellClass = [SimpleTableCellTableViewCell class]
[tableView registerClass:CellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(CellClass)];
```

And you can reuse that like this:

```
Class CellClass = [SimpleTableCellTableViewCell class]
[table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(CellClass)]
```

Comment: The problem is not the class but the name of the NIB

Comment: Would it be a problem if I'm using Main.storyboard?